# Function to flatten `('a list * b' list) list` to `'a list* 'b list` in OCaml

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I need a function in OCaml that will take a type of
    `('a list * b' list) list` and make of it
`'a list * b' list`. I have tried with the built in functions List.flatten and List.concat but they do not work, they require a type of `'c list list`. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the function `fold_left` like this :

You start with two empty lists working as accumulators. For every sub-lists in your the input list, you add the elements into the respective accumulator (elements of the first sub-list in the first accumulator and same thing for the second sub-list).

```
# let flatten l =
  let (l1,l2) =
    List.fold_left (fun (l1,l2) (x,y) ->
        (x :: l1, y :: l2)) ([], []) l in
  List.rev (List.flatten l1), List.rev (List.flatten l2);;
        val flatten : ('a list * 'b list) list -> 'a list * 'b list = <fun>
#
```

Comment: This is ok, but I need something to do 
`('a list * 'b list) list -> 'a list * 'b list` and not 
`('a * 'b) list -> 'a list * 'b list`

Comment: But it is still not what I need :( The order is not so important, what is important is what the input in the function is. Your gives `('a * 'b) list -> 'a list * 'b list` and I need `('a list * 'b list) list -> 'a list * 'b list`

Comment: Look my answer please, the function have the excepted type.

Comment: You seem to understand OCaml really good, this function I needed to finish another exercise that I posted up here, but even with this it does not work, if you have time it would be great if you could take a look at it 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858154/ocaml-function-with-data-type-tree/34878701#34878701

I am working on it for days now and I still do not have an answer :/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the functions `List.split` and `List.flatten`:

```
 let my_function l =
   let (fst_list, snd_list) = List.split l in
   List.flatten fst_list, List.flatten snd_list ;;
```

First the `split` function will generate and `'a list list` and a `'b list list`, then you just have to `flatten` them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no map for tuples and you need to decompose - e.g. using using split and flatten:

```
let splcat x = match List.split x with | (a,b) -> (List.flatten a, List.flatten b) ;;
```

That's how it looks on the commandline:

```
utop # splcat [([1;2],["a"]); ([3],["uvw";"xyz"]) ] ;;
- : int list * bytes list = ([1; 2; 3], ["a"; "uvw"; "xyz"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
let split2 l = (List.map fst l, List.map snd l)
let flatten2' (l1, l2) = (List.flatten l1, List.flatten l2)
let flatten2 l = flatten2' (split2 l)
```

Here, `split2` will turn a `('a list * 'b list) list` into a `('a list list * 'b list list)` (`fst` and `snd` return the first and second component of a pair, respectively) and `flatten2'` will individually flatten the two components. And `flatten2` will finally do what you require. You can also pack this into a single function, but I think this is easier to understand.

Note that neither `List.map` nor `List.flatten` is tail-recursive; if you need tail-recursive versions, there are other libraries that have them, or you can build them from the standard library using `rev_xxx` functions or write them from scratch.